# Dont see action item on action bar

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}

//This is menu_main.xml

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ordericon"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Just check that menu_main xml file has items in it

Comment: Yes, it does, here is the complete code:

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have override the `onPrepareMenu` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Why onPrepareOptionMenu to be used? i just want to show the item(image)on action bar.

Comment: But try doing this because this will prepare menu items to get listed.

Comment: See the documentation :- http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Comment: can there be a problem with the image saved in a folder?